# Can a 1-form be the sum of two 1-forms?

Tags: tensor-calculus, gauge-theory

I am interested in creating a Lie algebra-valued 1-form (gauge field/connection) for the Poincare algebra. Note that this algebra has two species of generators.

In SU(2) Yang-Mills, the connection was $A_\mu=A_\mu{}^a T^a$ where $T^a$ are the generators of SU(2).

In an analogous fashion, I can do the same for the PURE Lorentz algebra, $$\omega_\mu = \frac{1}{2}\omega_\mu{}^{ab}M_{ab}$$ where $M_{ab}$ are the (antisymmetric generators of the Lorentz algebra.

My first instinct for the Poincare algebra, was to naively do the same, $$A_\mu = e_\mu +\omega_\mu = e_\mu{}^a P_a + \frac{1}{2}\omega_\mu{}^{ab}M_{ab}$$ where $P_a$ are the spacetime translation generators of the Poincare.

This seems correct based on the work of others, [GR as a gauge theory: there's a Lorentz-valued spin connection, but what about a translation-valued connection?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437787/gr-as-a-gauge-theory-theres-a-lorentz-valued-spin-connection-but-what-about-a?rq=1)

but I worry about what it means the take the "sum" of two 1-forms. As far as I know, if you want "$A +B$" you do $A\wedge B$. But this is already and 2-form and I don't want that. Is this notion of the sum of differential forms completely bogus?

Comment: I can't comment on your application, it's above my pay grade, and I don't recall ever seeing $A+B=A\wedge B$. But the space of 1-forms is a vector space and addition works fine as far as I know.  If the 1-forms are expressed in the same basis, then add the coefficients.  But I may be missing something.

Comment: Thank you! "the space of 1-forms is a vector space" helped immensely

Comment: I thought I’d add a smidgen more, in case it clarifies anything. To make the space of $k$-forms, you take some vector space and turn it into a tensor algebra (and kill/mod-out the symmetric part). But an algebra is just a vector space with a bilinear form. The bilinear form here is your alternating tensor product or $\wedge$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every $p$-form $\omega_p$ is (sometimes even by definition) the sum of basic $p$-forms $\mathrm{d}x^{i_1\dots i_p} = \mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\wedge\dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_p}$ with real (or vector-valued, in the cases of e.g. forms with values in the Poincaré algebra) coefficients, i.e. 
$$ \omega_p = \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_p} \omega_{i_1\dots i_p}\mathrm{d}x^{i_1\dots i_p}.$$
The natural notion of summing two such forms is
$$ \omega_p + \omega'_p = \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_p}(\omega_{i_1\dots i_p} + \omega_{i_1\dots i_p}')\mathrm{d}x^{i_1\dots i_p},$$
where the $+$ on the r.h.s. is the addition in the vector space of coefficients.