# Why and where Poincaré gauge theory fails?

Tags: gravity, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I would like to post this question because I have seen no one post it in this explicit way.

From what I have seen, [Poincaré gauge theory](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=poincare+gauge+theory) uses connections (gauge fields) like the spin connection and the tetrad connection to set a theoretical formalism for interactions in gravitational physics.
These fields from my own perspective are not that relevant as the electromagnetic in ***U(1)*** and weak interaction ***SU(2)***, etc.

My point is that these fields don't have a well-established classical theory, and observations that can back up the predictions that they make, this is why the theory is harder than the other ones. this only says that Poincaré gauge theory is harder, I don't know maybe its more than that.

So I would like to know what you think about that?

My question is in the title it's: why and where Poincaré gauge theory fails?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, but in any case it seems opinion based.

Comment: @Oбжорoв sorry for the misunderstanding my question is in the title, I just wanted to give an overview of what I think may be the problem in Poincaré gauge theory. So the question is why and where Poincaré gauge theory fails?

Comment: There is plenty of stuff in the literature about interpreting general relativity in the vein of more traditional gauge theories (see e.g. the references in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437787/50583). Why do you think this approach "fails" and what does that mean? In particular, your assertion *"My point is that these fields don't have a well-established classical theory"* requires a reference.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I see, you are totally right, I thought that PGT failed in the interpretation test, maybe I rushed to the conclusion. My fault but if we discuss this  "My point is that these fields don't have a well-established classical theory", my thinking is that in contrast with the gauge boson of U(1) that has electromagnetism as a classical theory, the gauge fields of Poincaré gauge theory doesn't have a classical theory! can you tell me if this point is right?

Comment: You have to explain why you think we "don't have a classical theory" for anyone to answer this question. Note we're not talking about the Yang-Mills action here, so the usual folklore that non-Abelian Yang-Mills theories do not have interesting classical theories is irrelevant.

Comment: @ACuriousMind oh ok, let me explain my point; the fact that we have a classical theory that is well-approved makes us more comfortable with the theory we want to establish. The fact that a gauge boson of U(1) is a photon that is already described in another theory as electromagnetism makes it easy in the interpretation/ ontology of the boson field. But in PGT the vierbein and spin connections are a little bit tricky just because that they don't have a classical theory to support them. Please correct me if am wrong

Comment: This why I think it is relevant in some way that the Yang-Mills theory has a classical theory to back up the physical interpretation.

Comment: Couldn’t you argue that the classical electromagnetic fields are $E$ and $B$ and not the gauge field?